# App Store wouldn't recognize my Logic Pro X

Tags: mac-appstore, logic

I have LPX version 10.0.6 installed on my system and I recently heard that Apple just released a new updated version 10.0.7 on the App Store. However, not only I didn't receive any update notification on my App Store, it refuses to even recognize my installation! When I visit the LPX link on my App Store, it shows the price instead of "installed" like it says for Aperture, iWork, Garageband, etc. How can I make it recognize the installation?

P.S. Elsewhere, someone had suggested renaming the app to **Logic Pro** (removing the "X"). I did try it and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Where exactly did you get your copy of LPX from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic Pro X is only available on the Mac App Store** and the Logic Pro X bundle will contain a **MASReceipt** that tells the Mac App Store who the app is registered to.

This means the Mac App Store won't claim knowledge of the app unless you are signed in with the Apple ID that you used to purchase it. As you say you didn't purchase it from the Mac App Store, it won't be assigned to your Apple ID and the Mac App Store won't update it for you as it sees it immediately as pirated software.

**Aperture is available elsewhere on physical media.** This means that there won't be a Mac App Store receipt assigned to the app and the app can be assigned to an Apple ID.

This means that the Mac App Store will assign your Aperture that was purchased outside of the Mac App Store to the currently logged in Apple ID. This is the same for the retail version of iWork which can be purchased elsewhere and the Mac App Store will 'accept' it (like iLife).

---

You can read more about this problem when it occurred on this blog post by The Verge:

- [The Mac App Store is upgrading illegal and trial software for free](http://www.theverge.com/2013/10/24/5023560/the-mac-app-store-is-upgrading-illegal-and-trial-software-for-free)

Comment: Exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are signed in to the correct App Store account (you can sign out and in through the Store menu).

FYI I believe Logic Pro X was only ever available through the MAS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually bought your Logic Pro X from the App Store?

If not, where did you get it from?

You will need to buy it from the App Store to receive updates from that channel.

Comment: Nope, it's not a MAS purchase. Got it off elsewhere. The point is, I installed Aperture the exact same way but it's only LPX that MAS is refusing to recognize.

Comment: It sounds like you have a pirated copy then. Go buy the product and you'll get the updates without problems.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question completely. Like I said, Aperture and LPX both came from the same source, yet MAS refuses to recognize LPX and happily accepts Aperture. Question was why would the App Store recognize one app and not another?

Comment: @Amit Aperture is available elsewhere — see my answer

Answer (score 0):

- Login to AppStore with your Apple ID (if you are not already logged in)
- Check your purchases in App Store (Store > Purchases)
- Your Logic pro X should be on the list
- Install from here.